# Make top-level domain including ccTLD with www, subdomain as non-www and redirect all to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

A question about **.htaccess** file. I have went through almost all related questions, no answer gave out general solutions.

I would like **https for all, www to top level domain including country code top-level domain (co.uk, co.jp, com.cn), non-www to subdomain**.

How to achieve it?

I tried to edit .htaccess file like this (not just this snippet, I tried many others too):

```
# HTTPS forced with www
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS
```

It doesn't work on a subdomain, www will be prepended before it.

---

Updated:

After doing some investigation, I think the best pactice is not to have a general solution for both top-level domains and country code top-level domains.

So I am looking for 2 general solutions for TLDs and ccTLDs respectively, then I don't need to modify characters to something for example my domain.

Solution 1 should have expected redirection behavior for TLDs like below:

- `http://example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`
- `https://example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`
- `http://www.example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`
- `https://www.example.com` , keep unchanged
- `http://subdomain.example.com` -> `https://subdomain.example.com`

Solution 2 should have expected redirection behavior for ccTLDs like below:

- `http://example.co.uk` -> `https://www.example.co.uk`
- `https://example.co.uk` -> `https://www.example.co.uk`
- `http://www.example.co.uk` -> `https://www.example.co.uk`
- `https://www.example.co.uk` , keep unchanged
- `http://subdomain.example.co.uk` -> `https://subdomain.example.co.uk`

Comment: Are your domains/subdomains pointing to the same document root?

Comment: @AmitVerma Yes, currently subdomains like `staging1.example.com` are in the same root folder as the main domain.

Answer (score 0):

Open your wordpress site database -> wp_options.php

and change site_url and home_url like this:

```
http://example.com to https://www.example.com
```

Comment: This is one of ways to edit site url before modifying .htaccess file. I think I need to learn some basic thing first.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"

    # BEGIN WordPress
    # The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
    # dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
    # Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

Note: First set your site_url and home_url  like this https://www.example.com

Then change the .htaccess file otherwise site will not work if you change only on .htaccess but not change your site_url, home_url

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake by adding rules to .htaccess file before I changed site url. The www prepended to subdomain was automatically added by my hosting to control staging sites. I should ignore it.